# ClientAbortException, knowing the origin

Tags: tomcat, logging

I keep getting this exception repeatedly on my logs and it's affecting performance:

> ClientAbortException: 
>   java.net.SocketException: Software
>   caused connection abort: socket write
>   error

the problem is that this began after a recent update we've done to the application, in which only very minor modifications were made (no one that could be directly linked to the exception).

The most reasonable conclusion is that something in the update started this up, but I really cannot find the piece of code, so I was wondering if I could configure tomcat's logfile to print more information about the exception, like the ip address of the client that raised the error, the time when the exception ocurred, etc.

Any help please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This exception indicated that the remote client has aborted the connection, for example when downloading a file and the client cancel the downloading before ending.

Comment: I understand that. What I don't understand is why it has been suddenly appearing in the logs at a rate of approximately 5 time per minute... must be some misconfigured client... Anyway, this is an old problem and no longer bothers us. thanks for replying though.